# Files: One icon is large

Tags: nautilus, 15.04

Besides Files in Ubuntu 15.04 has become uglier (siderbar with black line as seperator between different categories), I noticed an error while displaying my files. One icon is very large, while others are normal. It happens only in one folder. Why is this happening, and what can I do to find causes of this problem?

[image]

Comment: What's the file type?

Comment: .osp (OpenShot Video Editor)

Comment: Does anything change if you change the icon theme?

Comment: If I rename file, it behaves normal. Only ".osp" cause this problem.

Comment: To the close voters: **Ubuntu 15.04 has been released and is on-topic!**

Comment: I have removed my vote.

Comment: Please, make a test with another icon theme.

Comment: Ok. I tried to change theme for Window, GTK+, Icons and Cursors in Tweak Tool, but nothing happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One potential solution is to replace `/usr/share/pixmaps/openshot.svg` with something different, maybe a png file. But that's more of a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

I solved as follows:

1 - Open the image with Inkscape and resized to 128x128;

2 - I exported to .png;

3 - I renamed the openshot.svg image to openshot.svg.bkp in directory: / usr / share / pixmaps /;

4 - I copied the image created with Inkscape to / usr / share / pixmaps / named: openshot.png.

Worked perfectly!